# Azure Event Hub diagnostic set up for User Errors

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics, azure-log-analytics

I am running a set up, where Stream Analytics job is reading from Azure Event Hub. Event Hub is contained within a namespace and there is consumer group created for SA specifically.

Recently I noticed `User Error` on Event Hub metrics.
[image]

Event Hub Namespace is configured to push all logs to OMS:

- ArchiveLogs
- OperationalLogs
- AutoScaleLogs
- KafkaCoordinatorLogs
- EventHubVNetConnectionEvent
- CustomerManagedKeyUserLogs
- KafkaUserErrorLogs

But that does not seem to cover that particular case, since I am unable to find that error in Log Analytics Workspace (e.g. by doing `search "UserError"` over last 24 hours).

Searching through docs is not to helpful either. Closest I have found was in .NET SDK for Azure:

```
Namespace: Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs
Assembly: Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.dll
UserError Identifies the exception as a user error and user needs to take an action to address the failure.
```

But that is not very helpful either, as it does not even indicate whether user is the sender or receiver of message.

What is the `UserError` in that case and how to pinpoint, what is actually happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User errors generally occur due to mistakes in the client application like,

User Errors in Event hub and service bus occurs due to similar reasons .. You can refer [Azure Service Bus Message Queue User Errors Metric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48707892/azure-service-bus-message-queue-user-errors-metric/51535162)

Comment: Thanks, that answers the first part of the question, namely what is `UserError` in this case. But is there any way to find, what is the root cause of this error on the receiver side (in that case this is Stream Analytics job)? Or even to identify receiver that failed (if there are multiple ones). Does Event Hub (or service bus in general) log such information?

Comment: Server will show only User Errors. Client application will get the detailed exception. In your case client is streaming analytics job, you can check the activity log of streaming analytics job. If no error found in activity log of streaming analytics job then raise support ticket with microsoft.